# Angular 4.3.3 : Why can't I get a DI in the Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Before I ask, I do not speak English very well.

first, I'm @angular@4.3.3 and my typescript version is ~2.3.3

Ask.

I lazy loaded the LoginModule

**AppRoute**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login#LoginModule' }
];

export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and my

**AppModule**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutes } from './routing/app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutes,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and

**LoginModule**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ErrorCodeService } from '../shared/service/error-code/error-code.service';
import { LoginService } from '../shared/service/login/login.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  providers: [
    ErrorCodeService,
    LoginService,
  ],
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

and 
**LoginService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ErrorCodeService } from '../error-code/error-code.service';
import { RequestCore } from '../request-core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService extends RequestCore {
  constructor(
    protected http: HttpClient,
    private errorCode: ErrorCodeService,
  ) {
    super(http, '/Login');
  }

  public load(userid: string, passwd: string): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
    .append('id', userid)
    .append('passwd', passwd);

    return this.get({ params })
    .map(res => {
      if (res.islogin === 'true') {
        return res.sendRedirect;
      }

      throw new Error(this.errorCode.getErrorMsg(res.reason));
    });
  }
}
```

**RequestCore**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpOptions } from '../models';

export abstract class RequestCore {
  constructor(
    protected http: HttpClient,
    private url: string,
  ) {
    // 개발 모드에서는 proxy를 위해 url에 /dev 접두어를 붙인다.
    if (environment.production === false) {
      url = '/dev' + url;
    }
  }

  protected get(options?: HttpOptions): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url, options);
  }

  protected post(options?: HttpOptions): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.url, {}, options);
  }
}
```

This is my error
[image]

I don't know why I can't DI in LoginService
ReuquestCore Are you making the wrong inheritance?

Teach me
Thank you!

Re:
  An error occurs when the first screen is loaded.
  When the next hmr is updated, no error occurs.

Comment: ErrorCodeService service is declared in the provider of app.module?

Comment: @Sreemat No, now app.module is not using ErrorCodeService. this servie using only LoginModule

Comment: @Sreemat how would that help ?